# ganesha <--> scorm 2004 : choice controlmode?

Tags: scorm2004

I need to use choice controlmode of scorm 2004, so I have done this very basic test :

This is my manifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<manifest xmlns="http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imscp_v1p1" xmlns:imsmd="http://ltsc.ieee.org/xsd/LOM" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:adlcp="http://www.adlnet.org/xsd/adlcp_v1p3" xmlns:imsss="http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imsss" xmlns:adlseq="http://www.adlnet.org/xsd/adlseq_v1p3" xmlns:adlnav="http://www.adlnet.org/xsd/adlnav_v1p3" identifier="MANIFEST-2F10A7A25FC691A6212BD9CB0B505D44" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imscp_v1p1 imscp_v1p1.xsd http://ltsc.ieee.org/xsd/LOM lom.xsd http://www.adlnet.org/xsd/adlcp_v1p3 adlcp_v1p3.xsd http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imsss imsss_v1p0.xsd http://www.adlnet.org/xsd/adlseq_v1p3 adlseq_v1p3.xsd http://www.adlnet.org/xsd/adlnav_v1p3 adlnav_v1p3.xsd http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imsss imsss_v1p0.xsd">
    <metadata>
        <schema>ADL SCORM</schema>
        <schemaversion>2004 3rd Edition</schemaversion>
    </metadata>
    <organizations default="ORG">
        <organization identifier="ORG" structure="hierarchical">
            <title>06 Navigation</title>
            <item identifier="page1" isvisible="true" identifierref="RES-page1">
                <title>page1</title>
                <item identifier="page2" isvisible="true" identifierref="RES-page2">
                    <title>page2</title>
                </item>
                <item identifier="page3" isvisible="true" identifierref="RES-page3">
                    <title>page3</title>
                </item>
                <imsss:sequencing>
                    <imsss:controlMode choice="true" choiceExit="false" flow="false" useCurrentAttemptObjectiveInfo="false" useCurrentAttemptProgressInfo="false"/>         
                </imsss:sequencing>
            </item>         
        </organization>
    </organizations>
    <resources>
        <resource identifier="RES-page1" adlcp:scormType="sco" type="webcontent" href="page1.html">
          <file href="page1.html" />
          <file href="js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" />
          <file href="js/SCORM_API_wrapper.js" />
          <file href="js/lmsCommunication.js" />
        </resource>
        <resource identifier="RES-page2" adlcp:scormType="sco" type="webcontent" href="page2.html">
          <file href="page2.html" />
          <file href="js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" />
          <file href="js/SCORM_API_wrapper.js" />
          <file href="js/lmsCommunication.js" />
        </resource>
        <resource identifier="RES-page3" adlcp:scormType="sco" type="webcontent" href="page3.html">
          <file href="page3.html" />
          <file href="js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" />
          <file href="js/SCORM_API_wrapper.js" />
          <file href="js/lmsCommunication.js" />
        </resource>
    </resources>
</manifest>
```

On page1, I connect to API and succeed to get username.

On click, I try to go to page 2 with this js code :

```
var scorm = pipwerks.SCORM;

$( document ).ready( init );

function init()
{
    scorm.version = "2004";

    connect();

    var learnerName = getValue( "cmi.learner_name" );

    $( "#Name" ).html( "Bonjour " + learnerName + " !!!" );

    $( "#goto2" ).click( goto2 );

    $( window ).unload( disconnect );
}

function goto2()
{
    if( getValue( "adl.nav.request_valid.choice.{target=page2}" ) == "true" )
    {
        setValue( 'adl.nav.request', '{target=page2}choice' );
        disconnect();
    }

    /* if( getValue( "adl.nav.request_valid.continue" ) == "true" )
    {
        setValue( 'adl.nav.request', 'continue' );
        disconnect();
    } */
}

function connect()
{
    if( !scorm.connection.isActive )
    {
        var isSuccess = scorm.init();               
        var msg = "Connexion : " + ( ( isSuccess )? "succès" : "échec" );
        log( msg, isSuccess );
    }
}

function disconnect()
{
    if( scorm.connection.isActive )
    {
        var isSuccess = scorm.quit();               
        var msg = "Déconnexion : " + ( ( isSuccess )? "succès" : "échec" );
        log( msg, isSuccess );
    }
}

function save()
{
    if( scorm.connection.isActive )
    {
        var isSuccess = scorm.save();               
        var msg = "Sauvegarde : " + ( ( isSuccess )? "succès" : "échec" );
        log( msg, isSuccess );
    }
}

function getValue( parameter )
{
    var value = null;

    if( scorm.connection.isActive )
    {
        value = scorm.get( parameter );
        var msg = "Get " + parameter + " : " + ( ( value )? value : "échec" );
        var isSuccess = ( value )? true : false;
        log( msg, isSuccess );
    }

    return value;
}

function setValue( parameter, value )
{
    if( scorm.connection.isActive )
    {
        var isSuccess = scorm.set( parameter, value );
        var msg = "Set " + parameter + " = " + value + " : " + ( ( isSuccess )? "succès" : "échec" );
        log( msg, isSuccess );
    }
}

function log( msg, isSuccess )
{
    $( "#console" ).append( "<div style=\"color:" + ( ( isSuccess )? "blue" : "orangered" ) + ";\">" + msg + "</div>" );
}
```

the scorm.set( 'adl.nav.request', '{target=page2}choice' ) doesn't work, it return an empty string.

Why is it not working ? an error in js or a bad tree in manifest maybe ?

I'm not succeed to find the good syntax and I'm not sure anymore to what way I have explore...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What does the following line return?

```
getValue("adl.nav.request_valid.choice.{target=page2}")
```

Comment: getValue("adl.nav.request_valid.choice.{target=page2}") return "", GetLastError after return 201, GetErrorString return 'Invalid argument error', GetDiagnostic too.

Comment: if getValue("adl.nav.request_valid.choice.{target=page2}") returns "", the line setValue('adl.nav.request', '{target=page2}choice') won't execute.

Comment: Can you give me the package or give more information about the problem?

Comment: I have make a copy of my package on github : https://github.com/tyd01/sco_navigation_test

Comment: What SCORM player are you testing your package on? Have you tested the package on SCORM Cloud (http://scorm.com/scorm-solved/scorm-cloud-features/)?

Comment: The line `getValue("adl.nav.request_valid.choice.{target=page2}")` is correct, and it is not expected to return empty characterstring.

Comment: Hello, I don't ever said it to you so thank you for your help. I have tested my package on scorm cloud and on this player `getValue("adl.nav.request_valid.choice.{target=page2}")` return me false. Before I was tested directly on Ganesha but I'm not sure anymore that SCORM compatibility is very functionnal. It wasn't support 4th Edition of SCORM 2004 so I'm using 3rd and there is some problems like that too...

Comment: I think the problem is because of the choiceExit of the page1 is false. If the choiceExit of the page1 is false, a choice navigation request cannot be processed.

Comment: I think that Ganesha is NOT SCORM compatible completely. It is better to test your packages on SCORM Cloud. If getValue("adl.nav.request_valid.choice.{target=page2}") returns False, page2 is not allowed to be launched.

Comment: Agree with you about Ganesha, unfortunately cutomer who need the package use this LMS, so I have to make it work on it. Now I can navigate between pages but I don't use SCORM function but js/as manipulation of document.location.href. Not a good practice but working. I think I will try more about SCORM for next projects. Thank you for your help, for me GANESHA IS NOT COMPATIBLE WITH SCORM IN FACT is a good conclusion. If anyone come to this page for the same  or comparable problem, change LMS.

Comment: Could you change the value of choiceExit of the page1 to true and then test the package on SCORM Cloud and then let me the result, please?